# Deploy gMSA account as task scheduler user account

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks, gmsa

I am trying to create a task on windows 2016 server, and need to deploy gMSA account as the log on account and below is the script i am using, i need to ensure that the option- "Run whether user is logged or not" gets selected,what change should be made to below code?

```
$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -Argument "NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted C:\Admin\Scripts\test.ps1 "
$trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -daily -At 5:05am
$Pri = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -UserId "Domain\gMSA" -LogonType ServiceAccount -RunLevel Highest
$task = New-ScheduledTask -Action $action -Trigger $trigger 
Register-ScheduledTask -Action $action -Trigger $trigger -TaskName "Taskname" -Principal $Pric
```

Comment: For one thing, it looks like you have a stray curly brace at the end. (No opening curly)

Comment: i made sure to use opening curly brace in the script, this was a typo

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a similar request as the SO topic and answers / accepted answer.

[Set a Scheduled Task to run when user isn't logged in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13965997/set-a-scheduled-task-to-run-when-user-isnt-logged-in)
But since you are using a gMSA, you'd never know what that password is.

So, you can create the task normally and then do say this...

```
schtasks /change /TN \YourTaskName /RU DOMAIN\gMSA_Name$ /RP
```

Or in pure PowerShell, you again set the Scheduled Task and then do this...

```
New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -UserID Domain\GMServiceAccount$ -LogonType Password
```

See the details of the above here:

[Active Directory - Scheduled Tasks Using a gMSA](https://coltonrepair.com/how-to-s/active-directory/16-active-directory-scheduled-tasks-using-a-gmsa)

Comment: thank you, for some reason schtaks command gives an error, but setting logontype as password in principal as the above snippet worked.

Comment: No worries, and remember to mark this as your accepted answer, if it indeed solves your issue,  for the benefit of the community who may find the need for this use case.

Comment: Dead link: 
https://coltonrepair.com/how-to-s/active-directory/16-active-directory-scheduled-tasks-using-a-gmsa