# Powershell closing automatic when running .ps1 file

Tags: windows, powershell, executionpolicy

I'm trying to create this .ps1 file: **see the full .ps1 markup**

```
# Definieer het pad waar de bestanden worden gekopieerd
$sourcePath = "C:\Users\Mr.Fox\AppData\Local\Hogwarts Legacy\Saved"

# Definieer het pad waar de bestanden naartoe worden gekopieerd
$destinationPath = "D:\Games\Saved HL"

# Zoek naar de laatst gebruikte mapnummer
$latestFolder = Get-ChildItem $destinationPath | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer } | Sort-Object { [int]($_.Name -replace '^\D+') } -Descending | Select-Object -First 1
if ($latestFolder -eq $null) {
    $folderNumber = 1
} else {
    $folderNumber = [int]($latestFolder.Name -replace '^\D+') + 1
}

# Maak de nieuwe doelmap aan
$newFolderName = "Backup_$("{0:D2}" -f $folderNumber)"
$newFolderPath = Join-Path $destinationPath $newFolderName
if (-not (Test-Path $newFolderPath)) {
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $newFolderPath | Out-Null
}

# Voeg uitvoer toe aan het logbestand
$logFile = Join-Path $destinationPath "backuplog.txt"
$date = Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
$logEntry = "$date - Backup gemaakt naar map $newFolderPath"
Add-Content $logFile $logEntry

# Vraag de gebruiker om bevestiging voordat het script wordt uitgevoerd
$confirm = Read-Host "Weet je zeker dat je het script wilt uitvoeren? Typ 'ja' om door te gaan."
Write-Host "Bevestiging: $confirm"

if ($confirm -eq "ja") {
    # Kopieer de bestanden van de bron naar de nieuwe doelmap
    Copy-Item $sourcePath $newFolderPath -Recurse -Force

    Write-Host "Het backupproces is voltooid en de uitvoer is toegevoegd aan het logbestand."
} else {
    Write-Host "Script uitvoering geannuleerd."
}

# Zet de PowerShell uitvoeringsbeleid terug naar de oorspronkelijke instelling
if ((Get-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser) -eq "RemoteSigned") {
    Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy Restricted
}

Read-Host "Druk op een toets om door te gaan..."
```

Then I try to click run with PowerShell, but it closes on me and what `Get-ExecutionPolicy -List` is telling me is that the current user's policy is `Restricted`, but when I try to enable it, it just goes back to `Restricted`, and I don't know why.

Can you help me out?

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-ExecutionPolicy -List

        Scope ExecutionPolicy
        ----- ---------------
MachinePolicy       Undefined
   UserPolicy       Undefined
      Process       Undefined
  CurrentUser      Restricted
 LocalMachine    RemoteSigned
```

I try to search online for a solution but didn't get very; I tried: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27755459

still the same problem

I get this response back when running `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted`

> Execution Policy Change
> The execution policy helps protect you from scripts that you do not trust. Changing the execution policy might expose
> you to the security risks described in the about_Execution_Policies help topic at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170. Do you want to change the execution policy?
> [Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "N"): y
> Set-ExecutionPolicy : Windows PowerShell updated your execution policy successfully, but the setting is overridden by a
> policy defined at a more specific scope.  Due to the override, your shell will retain its current effective execution
> policy of Restricted. Type "Get-ExecutionPolicy -List" to view your execution policy settings. For more information ple
> ase see "Get-Help Set-ExecutionPolicy".
> At line:1 char:1
>
> - Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
> - ```
>   + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (:) [Set-ExecutionPolicy], >SecurityException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExecutionPolicyOverride,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetExecutionPolicyCommand
>   ```

in regedit standard has no value but 'ExecutionPolicy' is already to Unrestricted though but still i cant run the script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**tl;dr**

- *Remove* the following from your script, given that it explicitly reverts the current user's execution policy to `Restricted`, preventing future execution of scripts:

  ```bash
  if ((Get-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser) -eq "RemoteSigned") {
      Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy Restricted
  }
  ```

  - Note that if your script is invoked with a *process* scoped execution policy - namely via the CLI's `-ExecutionPolicy` parameter (e.g. `powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass ...`), which is the equivalent of `-Scope Process` - such a policy by definition applies to *that process only*, so you needn't worry about restoring any *persistently* defined policies.
- Then open a PowerShell window and execute the following, which - given what your `Get-ExecutionPolicy -List` output shows -  will change the effective execution policy for your user account to `RemoteSigned`, which permits script execution, except for scripts downloaded from the web:

```bash
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser Undefined -Force
```

Read on for an explanation and alternatives.

---

**Background info**:

PowerShell's [execution policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Execution_Policies) can be defined in *multiple scopes*, but only *one* scope's policy is the *effective* one in a given session.

- [`Get-ExecutionPolicy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/get-executionpolicy) *without arguments* lists the *effective* policy.
- `Get-ExecutionPolicy -List` lists the policies defined for *all* scopes, in *descending order of precedence*:

  - That is, the *first* scope that has a value other than `Undefined` is also the effective one.
  - If *no* execution policy has ever been set, in any scope, the built-in defaults apply: `Restricted` (meaning that execution of script is *disallowed*) in *desktop* editions of Windows, and `RemoteSigned` in *server* editions.

Your `Get-ExecutionPolicy -List` shows that `Restricted` is defined in the `CurrentUser` scope (specific to the current user), and `RemoteSigned` in the `LocalMachine` scope.

Therefore, `Restricted` is the *effective* policy for you, preventing script execution.

You have three options, depending on your needs:

- If the `LocalMachine`-scope policy, `RemoteSigned`, works for you (it allows execution of script originating on the local file-system or network shares, but blocks script downloaded via a web browser, email client, or messenger application):

  - Simply *undefine* the `CurrentUser` policy, which then makes the `LocalMachine` policy take effect:

    ```bash
    Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser Undefined -Force
    ```
- If you want to retain a current-user policy but change it to allow script execution, run something like the following, specifying the desired policy (`RemoteSigned` in this example):

  ```bash
    Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser RemoteSigned -Force
  ```

If you additionally want to change the `LocalMachine`-scope policy, you'll need to do so from an *elevated* session (run as adminstrator).

Comment: @Xmaster1004. Yes, you can run it via Task Scheduler, and the most robust way to do that is to use a _process_-scoped execution policy that overrides whichever one is _persistently_ in effect, _for the given call only_, which is what the `-ExecutionPolicy` CLI parameter does (e.g., `powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ...`)

Comment: More detailed procces on how to do this with task Scheduler cuz i'm lost i cant get it to wok for some reason

Comment: @Xmaster1004, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75089634/45375) has sample code that sets up a scheduled task that calls PowerShell. If that doesn't help, I encourage you to ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Set execution policy to LocalMachine scope to Unrestricted. This scope is more important than the current user.

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted 
# by default its set to LocalMachine scope
```

Comment: @GrowITSupport this is what comes up i opened PowerShell as admin see the new awnser i made above

Comment: Open regedit and go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\ShellIds\Microsoft.PowerShell` (instead of 1 there may also be another number, check under each). Find 'ExecutionPolicy' key and change value to "Unrestricted".

Comment: @GrowITSupport standard has no value  but `'ExecutionPolicy' is already to to Unrestricted`

Comment: And if you set `Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy Unestricted` then this scope back to Restricted? Is your computer on a domain?

Comment: A policy set in the `CurrentUser` scope takes precedence over one in the `LocalMachine` scope. `Get-ExecutionPolicy -List` lists the scopes in order of precedence.