# Register Scheduled Task throwing Register-ScheduledTask : The parameter is incorrect error

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks, powershell-4.0

I modified the function to create the task taking out some unnecessary actions. Now when I try to run it I get the error below. I have tried following a couple different parameter schemes. But I can't figure out which parameter it is taking issue with. The error references line 124 char 5, but that is just the first character of the Register-ScheduledTask.

```
Register-ScheduledTask
        [-Force]
        [[-Password] <String>]
        [[-User] <String>]
        [-TaskName] <String>
        [[-TaskPath] <String>]
        [-Action] <CimInstance[]>
        [[-Description] <String>]
        [[-Settings] <CimInstance>]
        [[-Trigger] <CimInstance[]>]
        [[-RunLevel] <RunLevelEnum>]
        [-CimSession <CimSession[]>]
        [-ThrottleLimit <Int32>]
        [-AsJob]
        [<CommonParameters>]
```

```
Register-ScheduledTask : The parameter is incorrect.
At C:\com-code-client\main.ps1:124 char:5
+     Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName $taskName -TaskPath "\" -Action  ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (PS_ScheduledTask:Root/Microsoft/...S_ScheduledTask) [Register-ScheduledTask], CimExce
   ption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80070057,Register-ScheduledTask
```

```
$iscreateMATATask=$true
Function createMATATask {
    param(
        $taskName = "Start/Stop HIP",
        $taskDescr = "Starts and stops airwall to facilitate launching MATA",
        $taskScript = "C:\com-code-client\Start_Stop_HIP.ps1"
    )
    $exists = Get-ScheduledTask | Where-Object {$_.TaskName -like $taskName}
    if($exists)
    {
        Unregister-ScheduledTask -TaskPath "\" -TaskName $taskName -Confirm:$false
    }
    $action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "c:\windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -Argument "-WindowStyle Hidden -NonInteractive -Executionpolicy unrestricted -file $taskScript"
    $settings = New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet -AllowStartIfOnBatteries -DontStopIfGoingOnBatteries -RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable
    Register-ScheduledTask -User "System" -TaskName $taskName -TaskPath "\" -Action $action -Description $taskDescr -Settings $settings -RunLevel "Highest"
}
if($iscreateMATATask){
createMATATask
}
```

Comment: sounds like you are maybe calling it wrong? Can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77144738/edit) your question to provide some context around how you are calling the function?

Comment: I edited it to be the full function including how it is called.

Answer (score 0):

I went back to an older version of my function and found that if I kept the actions as an array, but still with just a single action is registered the task just fine. I also used the parameter scheme with Input Object. I am assuming it was maybe my action that was messing it up before.

```
Function create777MATATask {
    param(
        $taskName = "Start_Stop_HIP",
        $taskDescr = "Starts and stops airwall to facilitate launching MATA",
        $taskScript = "C:\com-code-client\Start_Stop_HIP.ps1"
    )
    $exists = Get-ScheduledTask | Where-Object {$_.TaskName -like $taskName}
    if($exists)
    {
        Unregister-ScheduledTask -TaskPath "\" -TaskName $taskName -Confirm:$false
    }
    $actions = @()
    $actions += New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "c:\windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -Argument "-WindowStyle Hidden -NonInteractive -Executionpolicy unrestricted -file $taskScript"
    $principal = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -UserId "System" -LogonType ServiceAccount -RunLevel Highest
    $settings = New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet -AllowStartIfOnBatteries -RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable
    $task = New-ScheduledTask -Action $actions -Description $taskDescr -Principal $principal -Settings $settings
    Register-ScheduledTask $taskName -TaskPath "\" -InputObject $task
}
```

Comment: I think it has to do with passing the user via "Nwe-ScheduledTaskPrincipal" vs. the -User parameter on "Register-ScheduledTask". It really does not like certain combinations and you have to play around with it for the desired results. Further information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70793765/4742987