# Create schedular using C# and run when user is logged in or not

Tags: c#, scheduled-tasks

I want to create a scheduler in Windows through c# code. I want the scheduler to run even if system is power off or even if user is not logged in.

I have tried following:

- `SCHTASKS: /Create /TN "New Task" /SC HOURLY /TR blah.exe /RU Test`  - creates a task but not run when user is not logged in
- `SCHTASKS /Create /TN "New Task" /SC HOURLY /TR blah.exe /RU System`  - gives Access denied error
- `SCHTASKS /Create /TN "New Task" /SC HOURLY /TR blah.exe /RU Administrator` - gives Access denied error
- `SCHTASKS /Create /TN "New Task" /SC HOURLY /TR blah.exe /RU usernameofsystem /RP passwordforthatuser` - gives Access denied error

I also see related posts on StackOverflow but didn't find any suitable answer which will work for me.

Comment: Just guessing but do subsequent attempts to create fail because you already have a scheduled task called 'New Task'?

Comment: Tempted to flag this as a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11190405/how-to-schedule-a-task-wether-the-user-is-logged-on-or-not-in-powershell). The usage of C# is irrelevant, since the "problem" lies with the task scheduler.

Comment: I have tried the link you are specifying but it is giving error "SCHTASKS /Create /TN "New Task" /SC HOURLY /TR blah.exe /RU System"           error is Access denied